# Como guardar en la BDD valores de un select2 multiple PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select2

Estoy tratando de guardar cada valor individualmente de un select2 multiple, por lo que si esa etiqueta añadida no esta la base de datos se insertara. `etiquetas_back.php`:

```
        $etiquetas = $_POST['etiquetas'];
        foreach ($etiquetas as $etiqueta){

            //comprobar si existe
            $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag='$etiqueta'");

            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            //la etiqueta no existe
            }else{
                //introducir la nueva etiqueta en la bdd
                mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES ('$etiqueta')");
            }
        }
```

Pero me inserta todo el array directamente en una nueva fila de la base de datos, como puedo solucionar esto? y que me inserte el valor de cada etiqueta individualmente.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120551/discussion-on-question-by-mikel-como-guardar-en-la-bdd-valores-de-un-select2-mul).

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu function en el JS asi

```
var form_data= $('#select2').val();
        form_data= JSON.stringify(form_data);
        console.log(form_data);
       /*Su log para ver la data */
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'text', 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/etiquetas_back.php',
               data: {
                      'form_data': form_data,
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener un array de todos los `text` o de cualquier otra propiedad posible, puedes usar `map`.

En el siguiente ejemplo se muestra el modo de extraer los `text`, guardándolos en `allTexts`, y hay otro ejemplo para obtener los `value` (en ese caso hay que buscar el `id`), el resultado se guarda en `allValues`. Luego, postearías esa variable al servidor.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.select-etiqueta').select2();

  /*Obtenemos todos los text*/
  var allTexts = $('#select2').select2('data').map(function(elem) {
    return elem.text
  });

  console.log(allTexts);
  
  /*Obtenemos todos los value*/
  var allValues = $('#select2').select2('data').map(function(elem) {
    return elem.id
  });

  console.log(allValues);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="select-etiqueta" name="etiquetas[]" id="select2" multiple="multiple">

  <option value="AL" selected>Alabama</option>

  <option value="WY" selected>Wyoming</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>


</select>
```

Comment: @Mikel ¿cuál foreach?

Comment: @Mikel ¿qué arroja ahora el `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @Mikel pero, ¿qué estás mandando desde Javascript? Si lo recoges como indico en la respuesta y lo mandas lo recibirás como un array de valores sin más.

Comment: @Mikel edita la pregunta y muestra cómo tienes ahora la función `save()` de tu Javascript. Para este caso podrías prescindir de FormData y mandar los valores que recoges directamente. Parece que estás anidando los valores demasiado, sin necesidad.

Comment: Ya la he editado, la cosa es que tambien tengo mas cosas en el formulario aparte del select, de ahi el hacer el `form_data` y ir añadiendole los datos.